# Error when building package of calibration_publisher while installing Autoware

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In autoware 1.12.0, I build the packages as the tutorial from source, and  I came across the errors by calibration_publisher as follows:

```
--- stderr: calibration_publisher                                                                                                
CMakeFiles/calibration_publisher.dir/src/calibration_publisher.cpp.o: In function `main':
calibration_publisher.cpp:(.text.startup+0x9b4): undefined reference to `cv::read(cv::FileNode const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [devel/lib/calibration_publisher/calibration_publisher] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/calibration_publisher.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Failed   <<< calibration_publisher  [ Exited with code 2 ]
Aborted  <<< ds4                                                                                                                              
Aborted  <<< detected_objects_visualizer                                                                                                  
Aborted  <<< decision_maker_panel
```

I have tried many times to fix it, but not work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332086/error-when-building-package-of-calibration_publisher-while-installing-autoware/) by [park](https://answers.ros.org/users/41098/park/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [park](https://answers.ros.org/users/41098/park/) on 2019-09-01**:
I add an empty file named "COLCON_IGNORE" in the package of calibration_publisher to avoid the bug, and finally build successfully

Ignore calibration_publisher, the demo test will fail.

**Comment by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) on 2019-09-02**:
Can you please provide information about your system? ROS version? Did you install OpenCV from source? (if so what version?).

**Comment by [park](https://answers.ros.org/users/41098/park/) on 2019-09-02**:
Sorry, I didn't provide enough information

Hardware Platform: Jetson AGX Xavier

OS: Ubuntu 18.04, installed by the [SDK Manager](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack)

ROS: melodic,   installed from sources by using  [installROSXavier script](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installROSXavier)

OpenCV: version is 3.4.3, installed from sources by using  [buildOpenCVXavier script](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/buildOpenCVXavier) in the path /usr/local, and during install ROS, 3.2.0 is also installed in the path /usr

I also notice that the error also existed in opencv's answers [camera_calibration.cpp: undefined reference to cv::read](https://answers.opencv.org/question/186560/camera_calibrationcpp-undefined-reference-to-cvread/)

**Comment by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) on 2019-09-02**:
I haven’t used the Jetson Hacks’ script you mentioned. I would recommend you to try a clean install. Don’t forget to run rosdep to install the opencv version to which ros’ cv_bridge was linked.( please also have in mind that Nvidia provides its own versions of OpenCV. In the case you selected that when you set up your AGX).

**Comment by [park](https://answers.ros.org/users/41098/park/) on 2019-09-02**:
Yes, I have tried the version of OpenCV provided by Nvidia, but it also failed. Next step, I will try to build autoware 1.12.0 on a x86_64 platform for test

**Comment by [park](https://answers.ros.org/users/41098/park/) on 2019-09-02**:
The error is caused by the codes in calibration_publisher.cpp;

```
fs["CameraExtrinsicMat"] >> CameraExtrinsicMat;
fs["CameraMat"] >> CameraMat;
fs["DistCoeff"] >> DistCoeff;
fs["ImageSize"] >> ImageSize;
fs["DistModel"] >> DistModel;
```

**Comment by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) on 2019-09-02**:
Please use apt versions of OpenCV. The easiest way is to use rosdep to install the correct ones.

**Comment by [park](https://answers.ros.org/users/41098/park/) on 2019-09-02**:
Yes I have also tried and it doesn't seem to be a problem of the OpenCV installation.

Now, I comment the following line:

```
fs["DistModel"] >> DistModel;
```

and passed the build,  very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error occurs when the opencv library cannot be loaded. Please refer to the address below
https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/pull/2090/commits/63abbb1c4d26be67ea0312b04b6dd9918cef3978

---

Originally posted by [jdj](https://answers.ros.org/users/40677/jdj/) with karma: 56 on 2020-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heylypp](https://answers.ros.org/users/63040/heylypp/) on 2020-11-11**:
Awesome! It works.

**Comment by [warriorUSP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36100/warriorusp/) on 2021-08-12**:
Great, this works for me too.
Basically adding opencv libraries path in CMakeLists.txt and package.xml fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I add a definition in the file of calibration_publisher.cpp:

```
static cv::Mat CameraExtrinsicMat;
static cv::Mat CameraMat;
static cv::Mat DistCoeff;
static cv::Size ImageSize;
static std::string DistModel
static cv::String DistModel_cv;
```

then modify the corresponding code to:

```
fs["DistModel"] >> DistModel_cv;
DistModel = DistModel_cv.operator std::string();
```

that is to convert cv::String to std::string, and the error is finally solved. I will test the demo next step.

---

Originally posted by [park](https://answers.ros.org/users/41098/park/) with karma: 21 on 2019-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1